# Where to put Symfony2 custom parameters I need?

Tags: database, configuration, symfony, parameters

I need to have some configuration for my bundle in **Symfony2**
Where is the best place to put them?
and how can I retrieve them from there?

I used my Default DB parameters in `PARAMETERS.INI` But I need Extra ones that I can retrieve them personally in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One should keep his parameters inside the bundles, for instance
`src/Company/SomeBundle/Resources/config/parameters.yml`

Answer (score 3):

To define any extra parameters you need, define them in your config.yml file. Something like:

```
# app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    my_mailer.class:      Acme\HelloBundle\Mailer
    my_mailer.transport:  sendmail
```

Then you can retrieve them anywhere that the service container is available, for example inside a controller, just like you retrieve any other service like doctrine or swiftmailer. For example, in a controller, do

```
$transport = $this->get('my_mailer.transport');
```

If you want, you can define these parameters in paramters.ini, you will get the same result.

Comment: Instead of $this->get('my_mailer.transport') you have to use $this->getParameter('my_mailer.transport') to access the parameter

Answer (score 1):

See the [How to expose a Semantic Configuration for a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/extension.html) cookbook entry. One of the advantages of this approach is that you can validate the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

use different parts in parameters.ini file. You could have a prod1 environment using parameters prefixed with prod1 and a prod2 with the same:

parameters.ini:

```
[parameters]
prod1_database_driver = pdo_mysql
prod1_database_host = 127.0.0.1

# ...

prod2_database_driver = pdo_mysql
prod2_database_host = localhost
```

They both use the prod.yml configuration but overwrite the stuff you want to read from the parameters.ini:

config_prod1.yml:

```
imports:
 - { resource: config_prod.yml }

// .. overwrite stuff here
```

Comment: how can i access them in controller?